# Backbone Collection Sync

Tags: backbone.js, collections, synchronization

I'm trying to figure out how to keep a collection of models in sync with my server. At the moment, my code looks like this, but it's clearly got a few problems...

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/block',

    ...

    sync: function() {
        _.each(this.models, function(model) {
            model.sync('create', model);
        });
    }

});
```

At the moment, when I call sync on my collection, it iterates through all of the models, and calls sync on each of them. I'm surprised, firstly that this isn't the default behaviour of a Backbone.Collection.sync method. Or am I misunderstanding what 'syncing collections' should do?

Secondly, my `model.sync('create', model);` line is a bit odd. Why do I have to pass model in when I'm calling the method on the model itself? Also, I'm manually calling 'create' which is clearly wrong. Shouldn't 'sync' be aware of whether it should created or update?

And also, shouldn't 'sync' be intelligent enough to call 'delete' on any models which have been removed from my collection?

I'm guessing I should be looking at customising the sync method on my model, but I'm still confused as to what I'm doing that is unusual that would require me to customise these sync methods.

I feel like I'm missing a fairly big point about sync.

Comment: Backbone consider model with no id as new and call create (on save method) otherwise call update (or patch). No that's not the default behavior of Backbone.Collection, I think you misunderstood `sync`, `fetch` and `save` methods of Backbone (read the docs then). Some of your points are not backbone/client-side but server-side.

Comment: aha. OK, so as I suspected, I overlooked something fairly basic, which was the save method. I skipped straight to sync. So from what I can see, save does the job I thought sync was doing. Sync is what is used for handling the response from the server from a save request to make sure that the model contains the attributes actually on the server after once saved. So what's the point of collection.sync? when doe sthat get fired?

Comment: Syncing collection all at once (in case you have /blog/:id/tags or anything like that). Your server must support nested relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, there isn't really an answer to this question, because it's an invalid question! I misunderstood what 'sync' was for. I am now using save as KiT O has pointed out.

Thanks.